# Grant privileges on several tables with specific prefix

Tags: mysql, database, sql-grant, database-permissions

I'm using the table prefix method for having several clients use the same database.  The number of tables created per client will be ~55.  Instead of doing all of the granting by manually listing out the tables, can I do something like the following?

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON database.prefix_* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: It's strange. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5989300/344347) is the same question with positive answers.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov I know your comment is kinda old, but this question is about table wildcard (which is not supported by MySQL) while your linked question is about database wildcard (which is supported)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Advance Note: This is not my answer. I found it at http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/202610 and have copied and pasted for simplicity credit to Stephen Cook

You can use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES view to generate the GRANT 
statements for you.  Write a query along these lines:

```
SELECT   CONCAT('GRANT SELECT ON test.', TABLE_NAME, ' to ''foouser'';')
FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test'
      AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'foo_%'
```

Then run it, copy the results, and run those results as a query or 
script.  You can of course get as crazy as you want with this, for 
example if you do this for many users maybe write a stored procedure 
that takes a parameter for the username and can therefore be used as a 
tool whenever you need it.

It isn't a syntax you asked for, but it is a nice trick that works.

--

Replace the table schema 'test' with the name of your database. foo_% can be replaced with the appropraite prefix_%

I tried this on my own and it worked great.

Comment: OP didn't have the courtesy to accept this answer, but it helped me so +1

Comment: You saved the day for me sir!

Comment: awsome solution, if you need to add specific privileges on a lot of (prefixed) tables.

Comment: Same works for PostgreSQL too if you just lose the single quotes concatenated around the username. +1

Comment: Nice solution. But it does not cover a case a new table with that prefix is being created after a user was granted privileges.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you can wildcard table names, you can definitely wildcard database names though. Watch out though as `_` is a wildcard matching any single character (like `.` in a regular expression).

The Documention is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html

> The “_” and “%” wildcards are
>   permitted when specifying database
>   names in GRANT statements that grant
>   privileges at the global or database
>   levels. This means, for example, that
>   if you want to use a “_” character as
>   part of a database name, you should
>   specify it as “\_” in the GRANT
>   statement, to prevent the user from
>   being able to access additional
>   databases matching the wildcard
>   pattern; for example, GRANT ... ON `foo\_bar`.* TO ....

Comment: It seems like we CANNOT use wildcard for table names

Answer (score 0):

using bash:

```
mysql -Ne "show tables from test like 'foo_%'" | xargs -I {} mysql -Ne "GRANT SELECT ON test.{} TO 'foouser'@'%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `database`.`prefix\_%`.* TO  'username'@'localhost'
```

works fine (tested with MySQL 5.6.12 on Windows)

Comment: This only works for dynamically specifying the name of the database, instead of dynamically specifying the table names, unfortunately.

Comment: This does not work in 5.7.  As described in the docs at [GRANT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#grant-quoting): _"When a database name not is used to grant privileges at the database level, but as a qualifier for granting privileges to some other object such as a table or routine, wildcard characters are treated as normal characters."_