# Can I grant access to databases with prefix then wild card?

Tags: mysql

Can I `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON a*.* TO 'my_user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;` ?

I just want the user to only have access to all databases beginning with "my_prefix_"  but not, for instance, to "mysql".

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Yes, you can.

This is what phpMyAdmin does when I make a user `jaap` and use the option `Grant all privileges on wildcard name (username\_%)`:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  `jaap\_%` . * TO  'jaap'@'localhost';
```

That's what you mean, right?

**PS**
As you can see, the `_` is escaped, because in (My)SQL an unescaped `_` means 'one character'. (Like `.` in regex.) In this case, you want the `_` to be literal, so databases must start with `jaap_`

Comment: is there a similar wildcard for table name prefix?