# How Grant all privileges on prefixed wildcard name in mysql 8

Tags: mysql-8.0

In my database, there are many database retaliated to a one project like below

```sql
flatmon
flatmon_user
flatmon_login
flatmon_transaction
.....
```

I just want the user to only have access to all databases beginning with "flatmon"
But, in mysql 8 it's doesn't work. (i tried in mysql 5.7 then it worked)
i set privileges like below.

```sql
CREATE USER 'flatmonuperadmin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '7c652ab5-5658-417a-9680-8a4265752233';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `flatmon\_%`.* TO 'flatmonuperadmin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have db named "**rf-facade**"
You can use:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `rf-facade`.* TO 'rf_facade_developer';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[Try This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58817095/10954257)

```
Grant all privileges on `some_db_%`.* to 'user'@'IP' with grant option;
```

Comment: "some_db_" is string you want to match