# MariaDB Grant wildcard database name

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-grant, mariadb-10.3

In my MariaDB database, I have created user with wildcard(%) database name with GRANT OPTION permission.
When this particular user tries to run a GRANT command to another user over a GRANTED database it gives a

> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'localhost' to database 'dbprefix_dbpostfix'

If I check GRANTS of this particular user it showing like below.

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EVENT, TRIGGER ON `dbprefix%`.* TO 'dbuser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

My database name is like "dbprefix_dbpostfix"

Comment: `Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost'` but You're granting for user `dbuser@localhost`

Comment: @num8er - I have updated the names. Basically it is same user.

Comment: i think You've to get list of databases with prefix and grant them

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988842/can-i-grant-access-to-databases-with-prefix-then-wild-card

Comment: have You done: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after granting user?

Comment: @num8er Yes. I have flush the privileges

Comment: ok, You've granted, but have You created that users? cause grant inserts to mysql.user table row with grants

Comment: @num8er The databases are dynamically creating according to the pattern. Hence it is not possible to list the databases and grant

Comment: @num8er User is already there

Comment: nope, for every grant it creates new user in mysql.user table :) that's why it says access denied. if You don't believe me do: `use mysql; select * from user;`

Comment: I recommend You to use professional IDE like DataGrip or better MySQL Workbench and manage users correctly.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/images/wb-navigator-users-privileges-login.png

Comment: Why does that user need more than one `DATABASE`?