# MySQL Granting privileges to users

Tags: mysql, sql

I create an user called abc. Now I need to grant read privilege to him. But he should be get read privilege only for the views in database. How can I implement this?

Comment: What is a `grantion`?

Answer (score 3):

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)

`GRANT SELECT ON database.view TO 'abc'@'localhost';`

Also, there is a [neat trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887104/grant-privileges-on-several-tables-with-specific-prefix), which (combined with `SHOW FULL TABLES IN database_name WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW';` ) will allow you to generate code for all views you need.

Comment: Thank you very much. Here I have more than one view. I need to give priviledges to all the views.

Comment: @IsuruHerath You can easily do this with a script. Simply get list of all views `SHOW FULL TABLES IN database_name WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW';` and store in array, and then go through array giving the permissions on each item! For example, you can do this with bash or php

Comment: But I have asked to write a querry for this.

Comment: @IsuruHerath tell the person, who asked you, that this is impossible

Comment: @IsuruHerath have you finished your task? Was I right, when told you, that this can't be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GRANT 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-privileges

```
GRANT SELECT ON db2.invoice TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
```