# MySQL - How to grant privileges to user on specific tables defined with wildcard?

Tags: mysql, sql-grant, database-permissions

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2668660/248616), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5887172/248616), we can use wildcard when granting privileges to user.

```
grant all on `someSchema\_%`.* to `someUser`@`%`;
```

Though wildcard CANNOT be applied to table name i.e.

```
grant all on `someSchema\_%`.`someTable%` to `someUser`@`%`;
grant all on `someSchema\_%`.`someTable\_` to `someUser`@`%`;
```

My [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=MySQL%20-%20How%20to%20grant%20privileges%20to%20user%20on%20specific%20tables%20defined%20with%20wildcard&oq=MySQL%20-%20How%20to%20grant%20privileges%20to%20user%20on%20specific%20tables%20defined%20with%20wildcard&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.315j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) results non-helpful so I ask here - how can we use `wildcard` for *BOTH schema name and table name* in MySQL `GRANT` command?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot do that. Wilcards are only possible for the database name and the host (apart from the `*`-wildcard to mark all tables)

Comment: There is a workaround here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887104/grant-privileges-on-several-tables-with-specific-prefix